# Symfony logs in Heroku

Tags: symfony, logging, heroku

I start to work in a new project, this project is deployed in Heroku and we have like 120.000 errors at day, I think that something strange is happening and we need to fix it, but my colleagues told me that this is normal. I will try to deep into the logs but there are not information about errors, I think that configuration in symfony is correct to show the logs in heroky but I only see access logs but not error log.

I also create a test environment to check how to monitored logs but I am not able to get symfony logs in heroku console. The configuration is :

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler:      nested
        nested:
            type:  stream
            path:  "php://stderr"
            level: debug
        console:
            type:  console
```

I forze an error in my symfony application and the logs that I get with heroku logs --tail are:

```
2017-09-01T07:40:44.279088+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.100.140.36 - - [01/Sep/2017:07:40:44 +0000] "GET /app_dev.php/en HTTP/1.1" 500 80447 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
2017-09-01T07:40:44.272796+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/app_dev.php/en" host=www-example.com request_id=bf374539-e700-42f4-a6c5-be3d16247824 fwd="46.231.19.210" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=208ms status=500 bytes=80759 protocol=http
2017-09-01T07:40:44.532016+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.78.131.113 - - [01/Sep/2017:07:40:44 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 745 "http://www-example.com/app_dev.php/en" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
2017-09-01T07:40:44.604166+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.100.140.36 - - [01/Sep/2017:07:40:44 +0000] "GET /app_dev.php/_wdt/43a348 HTTP/1.1" 200 41605 "http://www-example.com/app_dev.php/en" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
2017-09-01T07:40:44.600359+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/app_dev.php/_wdt/43a348" host=www-example.com request_id=73ca3964-6bda-4da5-983e-621b45d8dc3a fwd="46.231.19.210" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=126ms status=200 bytes=41806 protocol=http
2017-09-01T07:40:44.528413+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=www-example.com request_id=034f1c77-8d2b-450a-8a6f-5053701b8e8e fwd="46.231.19.210" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=974 protocol=http
```

In local environment I also can check this errors on nginx error log.

How can I do to get the errors in heroku logs that I see when I use the dev environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, There was two problems:

1- The first problem why I don't see the logs it was because I was trying with dev enviroment and this enviroment it was not configured to send logs in heroku environment. Yes, I am little bit distrated.

2- Once I realize that I was making the first mistake, I also face the same problem , i was not able to check the logs. I am going to explain a little bit to understand the solution: 
I upgrade my database with doctrine migrations and I use redis to cache metadata. The problem was that I need to flush Redis to load metadata with new changes. Once I did that, it start to work.

Comment: Ok so this has nothing to do with Symfony logs in Heroku. I recommend you to delete your question.